# How can I enlarge an opening in wall tile for an electrical box?

Tags: tile, backsplash

When the backsplash was installed, the hole left for an outlet box is a tad too small. What is my best option to enlarge the hole to slide the box in?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

An angle grinder with a diamond-dust blade will cut that tile easily. It's very messy, of course, so have a helper hold a strong vacuum right near the blade as you cut.

You might also be able to just file enough material away to get it to fit. A common rasp or other abrasive tool could work. Wall tile is relatively soft, but the glaze isn't, so expect some dulling of such tools to occur. Don't use your best woodworking equipment.

Comment: I started with a file but some glaze chipped. Luckily it will be under the face plate. Was nervous about going further with the file.

Answer (score 1):

When I did my backsplash, I used a Dremel rotary tool with  small diamond cutoff wheel made to cut tile. It worked like a charm. I did have to squirt water on the tile/blade to prevent overheating. I have seen tile files but have not used them.

Answer (score 0):

To help any other's in the same situation, since I didn't need to remove much to widen the opening, I just used a low grit sandpaper and was able to remove enough material. Cheaper than destroying a file or rasp. Thanks for the tips!